# How validate a require field only when another has a value laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form that have 2 options, image or video, only one of these are required at the same time, so if the user send a image the video field is not longer required, but the video field could still be present and empty in the payload, i have a form request where i need something like this.

```
'image'   => 'required_if_empty:video|image|max:3000',
'video'   => 'required_if_empty:imagen|url|max:255'
```

if image is empty and video is not empty: pass

if image is not empty and video is empty : pass

if image is not empty and video is not empty : fail

if imge is empty and video is empty : fails

Comment: You may have a look at Complex Conditional Validation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
'image' => 'required_without:video',
'video' => 'required_without:image',
```

However this will not satisfy following condition:

> if image is not empty and video is not empty : fail

I would leave this as a comment as it's not complete answer but I don't have enough points and quote below seems to contradict the quote above so this might be what you're looking for.

> if the user send a image the video field is not longer required, but the video field could still be present and empty in the payload

For more check predefined validation rules [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#available-validation-rules), and custom validation rules [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules).